# How can I set the time zone as null in Google Calendar Integration?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I have written a code in ASP.NET MVC that integrates with google calendar API and sets an event into the user's calendar. My Code is :

```
 public static string CreateEvent(CalendarEventViewModel model)
        {
            string Id = "";
            // List events.
            Event newEvent = new Event()
            {
                Summary = model.Summary,
                Location = model.Location,
                Description = model.Description,
                Start = new EventDateTime()
                {
                    DateTime = DateTime.Parse(model.StartDateTime),
                    TimeZone = "America/Los_Angeles",
                },
                End = new EventDateTime()
                {
                    DateTime = DateTime.Parse(model.EndDateTime),
                    TimeZone = "America/Los_Angeles",
                },
                Recurrence = new String[] { "RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=1" },
                Attendees = new EventAttendee[] 
                {
                     new EventAttendee() { Email = model.CompanyEmailAddress },
                },
                Reminders = new Event.RemindersData()
                {
                    UseDefault = false,
                    Overrides = new EventReminder[] 
                    {
                        new EventReminder() { Method = "email", Minutes = 24 * 60 },
                        new EventReminder() { Method = "sms", Minutes = 10 },
                    }
                }
            };

            String calendarId = "primary";
            if (model.IsInsert)
            {
              Event createdEvent =   SharedService.service.Events.Insert(newEvent, calendarId).Execute();
              Id = createdEvent.Id;
            }
            else
            {
                SharedService.service.Events.Update(newEvent, calendarId, model.Id).Execute();
                Id = "";
            }
            return Id;
        }
```

It works perfectly but here I need to remove the timezone or set it to null `TimeZone = "America/Los_Angeles",` because the admin and user's time zone are different. For example:- If admins set the event for 5:00 am, then the time for events in the user's google calendar also must be 5:00 am due to the timezone currently there are different. How Can I do this?

I tried removing the timezone part from the code but I got an error saying the timezone was missing.

Comment: The thing is IIR by default events are inserted in at the time zone of the calendar itself. So if the admin wants to add an event in the users calendar for 5 am the users time then it should insert by default into the users calendar at 5 am .   However if the admin wants to insert an event at 5 am America/Los_Angeles time then they will need to add the time zone and then it will be converted to that time in the users calendar.

Comment: @DaImTo Currently Admin is adding the time at 8:00 - 11:00 AM but in the user's calendar, it's showing from 2:00 -5:00 PM what is the cause of it?

Comment: @DaImTo I think because its development is in Nepal and its live server is in the US the time difference is + 5:45 GMT. Should I change the time zone in the google calendar app and it will work? or I have to something else for it.

Comment: Hi, I posted an answer. Let me know if this answers your question or if you need more indications.

Comment: @DaImTo I just figured out that the timezone in Event ``` (TimeZone = "America/Los_Angeles") ``` is not working. The time zone selected is the default time zone of the location from which the server is hosted. For Example:- If I run it from Nepal(GMT 5:45) in my development, then the time zone of the calendar is GMT + 5:45 similarly if I run it from the hosted server  (GMT +0:00), then the time zone of the calendar is (GMT +0:00). Pleasde Help why is this happening.

Answer (score 1):

#### Issue:

You need to specify a timeZone, either in `start.dateTime` or in `start.timeZone`. From the [API docs](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events):

> **start.dateTime**: The time, as a combined date-time value (formatted according to RFC3339). **A time zone offset is required unless a time zone is explicitly specified in timeZone**.

#### Explanation:

A timezone is needed in order to specify a specific dateTime for the event. It indicates which timezone the dateTime refers to. For example, let's say the time is `5:00 AM`. 5:00 AM where? In LA? In Nepal? 5:00 AM in LA is not the same time as 5:00 AM in Nepal. And a specific event can only start at a specific time. If it starts at 5:00 AM in LA, it starts at (I think) 5:45 PM in Kathmandu. You cannot have a specific event starting both at 5:00 AM in LA and in Kathmandu: that's two different times!

So, the following is not possible. If two users (and their Calendars) are in different timezones, a specific event will show in different times:

> For example:- If admins set the event for 5:00 am, then the time for events in the user's google calendar also must be 5:00 am due to the timezone currently there are different.

Of course, you can always change the time zone for your Calendar (see section `Change the time zone of one calendar` [here](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37064)), but this won't change the actual time an event starts; it will just show the start times in a different time zone. An event starting at 5:00 AM LA time will still start at 5:45 PM Nepal time.

**If you really want an event to start at 5:00 AM both in LA and in Kathmandu time, you will have to create two different events**.

Comment: I don't really want to start both events at 5:00 A.M. What I actually want is to set the time zone to users. For example, If I from LA select the time as 5.00 A.M. and I send the event invitation to Nepal's, then the time should be 5.00 A.M. in Nepal Time Zone. I don't care what ever the time zone sets in LA's calendar

Comment: Currently the TimeZone = "America/Los_Angeles" is not just working. The Time Zone is selected from the email that is going to send an event invitation.

Comment: @BirazDahal So, you want to set the timezone for the specific attendee? You would need access to the attendee Calendar in order to retrieve this information. Do you have this access? Has the attendee shared the Calendar with you?

Comment: Yes, I have the timezone for the specific attendee saved in the database. but I don't have access to use calendar. Suppose I have to send it to the three users A, B, and C. I have the Time Zone like US/Central, US/Mountain, US/pacific for each and every specific individual. Can it be done with this information?

Comment: @BirazDahal I don't understand your request. You want to have three attendees, each one on a different timezone. But the event datetime can only be one. Each attendee will see the event on their calendar's own timezone, there's no need to specify a timezone for each of them. Can you clarify this?

Comment: Okay, I will start from the beginning. Suppose I have to send event 1  invitation to user A whose timezone is GMT + 1:00 and I have to send another event 2 invitation to user B whose timezone is GMT + 3:00. Event 1 and Event 2 are 2 different events. Now, the event 1 timezone should be GMT +1:00, and event 2 timezones should be GMT +3:00. I also have the timezone for each attendee. How can this be done? or it isn't possible to do it? Please Help

Comment: To make it simple let's say the time zone should be according to the attendee and in my case, there won't be more than one attendee for one event.

Comment: @BirazDahal Well, in this case why can't you set `TimeZone` to the desired timezone coming from the database. You know the attendee, and you know what timezone corresponds to the attendee, so what's stopping you from setting the right timezone for the attendee? Or maybe I'm still not understanding this?

Comment: You got it exactly what I wanted to say. That's the problem I am facing currently, even I set the timezone from the database, the timezone in the calendar is not according to the TimeZone I set. It is always the timezone from where I am running the application. For Ex:- In the above code I have set TimeZone = "America/Los_Angeles", but when I run the same code in my development mode the timezone in the calendar is always GMT +5:45 because I am running it from Nepal. There isn't any use of TimeZone = "America/Los_Angeles".

Comment: @BirazDahal Alright, I think I understand your issue now. In this case, I think the problem is that `model.StartDateTime` and `model.EndDateTime` already contain information about a timezone, so the dateTime (including timezone) is defined by that, and not by `TimeZone = "America/Los_Angeles"`. Taking this into account, could you provide the code related to `model.EndDateTime`?

Comment: The model.EndDateTime and model.StartDateTime value is :- 
  `StartDateTime = DateTime.Parse("11/01/2020 8:00:00 AM") 
EndDateTime = DateTime.Parse("11/01/2020 9:00:00 AM") `
Is something wrong here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223406/discussion-between-iamblichus-and-biraz-dahal).