# How to define timezone in Google Calendar Integration API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I have written a code for Google Calendar Integration that sends an event invitation to the user.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Apsara(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
                var flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
                {
                    ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
                    {
                        ClientId = "CLIENT_ID",
                        ClientSecret = "CLIENT_SECRET"
                    },
                    Scopes = new[] { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events" },
                    DataStore = new FileDataStore("Calendar.Api.Auth.Store")
                });

                var token = new TokenResponse
                {
                    AccessToken = "ACCESS_TOKEN",
                    RefreshToken = "REFRESH_TOKEN"
                };

                var credentals = new UserCredential(flow, Environment.UserName, token);

                var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credentals,
                    ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
                });

                // Define the parameters of the request.
                EventsResource.ListRequest request = service.Events.List("primary");
                request.TimeMin = DateTime.Now;
                request.ShowDeleted = false;
                request.SingleEvents = true;
                request.MaxResults = 10;
                request.OrderBy = EventsResource.ListRequest.OrderByEnum.StartTime;


                Event newEvent = new Event()
                {
                    Summary = "Google I/O 2015",
                    Location = "800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103",
                    Description = "A chance to hear more about Google's developer products.",
                    Start = new EventDateTime()
                    {
                        DateTime = DateTime.Parse("11/01/2020 8:00:00 AM"),
                        TimeZone = "US/Central",
                    },
                    End = new EventDateTime()
                    {
                        DateTime = DateTime.Parse("11/01/2020 9:00:00 AM"),
                        TimeZone = "US/Central",
                    },
                    Recurrence = new String[] { "RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=1" },
                    Attendees = new EventAttendee[]
                   {
                     new EventAttendee() { Email = "testgoogle@gmail.com" },
                   },
                    Reminders = new Event.RemindersData()
                    {
                        UseDefault = false,
                        Overrides = new EventReminder[]
                       {
                        new EventReminder() { Method = "email", Minutes = 24 * 60 },
                        new EventReminder() { Method = "sms", Minutes = 10 },
                       }
                    }
                };

                String calendarId = "primary";
                service.Events.Insert(newEvent, calendarId).Execute();

                return View();                 
        }
```

The code runs fine but here in the code I mention the time zone `TimeZone = "US/Central"`, but after sending the invitation in the user's google calendar the timezone is not `US/Central`. The time zone is selected from where we run the project. For Example:- In development mode, If I run it from GMT 0:00 the time zone in google calendar is GMT 0:00, and if I run it from GMT + 5:45 then the timezone in google calendar is GMT + 5:45 . How can I set the fix timezone `TimeZone = "US/Central"` , so that from wherever I run the project the time zone is US/Central?

Comment: Time zone is associated to the account and not the "project" and so any event will show up in that account's set timezone, see [this](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37064?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en), though you mention that you "run the project" from a different timezone, can you add some more details of how you do this? Is the project run from different accounts? What is the form of the integration? Finally, can you clarify that the end result you want to see is an event that shows the same timezone, no matter where you are?

Comment: @iansedano Currently I am developing an application from Nepal whose timezone is GMT +5:45. In development mode,while running the application the time zone in the user's google calendar is GMT +5:45,but the application is hosted in a server whose time zone is  GMT 0:00.So while running this hosted application the timezone in the user's calendar is GMT 0:00. What I wanted to do is I have the time zone for each user's saved in the database,so I want to send in their respective time zone.Suppose For user A the google event should be on User A's time zone and for B it should be User B's time zone.

Comment: @iansedano  The time zone that is associated with the account is GMT  -6:00, but the time zone in the user calendar is never GMT -6:00. Please Help

Comment: I noticed that you posted pretty much the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64346734/how-can-i-set-the-time-zone-as-null-in-google-calendar-integration?rq=1) - please don't post duplicates. Better to edit your original question to make it more clear what you are trying to do. Though I think you are approaching the problem in the wrong way, you need to calculate when the event should be in the service account timezone and create event, not change timezones before creating _every_ event.